# Registration Form with Formik,Yup,Mui not working

Tags: reactjs, yup, formik-material-ui

Good afternoon everyone. I'm trying to create a registration form using Formik, MUI, and yup. I did the same thing with my login and it's working perfectly with the backend post etc. Also, my auth/register for backend is working, tested with the postman. My problem is whenever I press the Register Button nothing happens. Not even the console logging of my 'Test' String.

```js
import {
    Box,
    Button,
    MenuItem,
    TextField,
    Typography,
    useMediaQuery,
    useTheme,
} from '@mui/material'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as yup from 'yup'

const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
    firstName: yup.string().required('required'),
    lastName: yup.string().required('required'),
    userType: yup.string().required('required'),
    userName: yup.string().required('required'),
    email: yup.string().email('invalid email').required('required'),
    password: yup.string().required('required'),
    confirmPassword: yup.string().required('required'),
})

const initialValuesRegister = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    userType: '',
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
}

const type = [
    {
        value: 'Student',
        label: 'Student',
    },
    {
        value: 'Teacher',
        label: 'Teacher',
    },
]

const FormRegister = () => {
    const { palette } = useTheme()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')

    const register = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
        const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:3001/auth/register',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(values),
            }
        )

        const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json()
        onSubmitProps.resetForm()

        if (savedUser) {
            console.log(savedUser)
            navigate('/')
        }
    }

    const handleFormSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
        console.log('Test')
        console.log(values, onSubmitProps)
        await register(values, onSubmitProps)
    }

    return (
        <Formik
            onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
            initialValues={initialValuesRegister}
            validationSchema={registerSchema}
        >
            {({
                values,
                errors,
                touched,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange,
                handleSubmit,
                resetForm,
            }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Box
                        display="grid"
                        gap="30px"
                        gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                        sx={{
                            '& > div': { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : 'span 4' },
                        }}
                    >
                        <TextField
                            label="First Name"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.firstName}
                            name="firstName"
                            error={Boolean(touched.firstName) && Boolean(errors.firstName)}
                            helperText={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            label="Last Name"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.lastName}
                            name="lastName"
                            error={Boolean(touched.lastName) && Boolean(errors.lastName)}
                            helperText={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            id="outlined-select"
                            select
                            label="Select Type"
                            defaultValue="Student"
                        >
                            {type.map((option) => (
                                <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                                    {option.label}
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </TextField>
                        <TextField
                            label="User Name"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.userName}
                            name="userName"
                            error={Boolean(touched.userName) && Boolean(errors.userName)}
                            helperText={touched.userName && errors.userName}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            label="Email"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.email}
                            name="email"
                            error={Boolean(touched.email) && Boolean(errors.email)}
                            helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.password}
                            name="password"
                            error={Boolean(touched.password) && Boolean(errors.password)}
                            helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            label="Confirm Password"
                            type="password"
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={values.confirmPassword}
                            name="confirmPassword"
                            error={
                                Boolean(touched.confirmPassword) &&
                                Boolean(errors.confirmPassword)
                            }
                            helperText={touched.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword}
                            sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
                        />
                    </Box>
                    {/* BUTTONS */}
                    <Box>
                        <Button
                            fullWidth
                            type="submit"
                            sx={{
                                m: '2rem 0',
                                p: '1rem',
                                backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
                                color: palette.background.alt,
                                '&:hover': { color: palette.primary.main },
                            }}
                        >
                            REGISTER
                        </Button>
                        <Typography
                            onClick={() => {
                                navigate('/')
                                resetForm()
                            }}
                            sx={{
                                textDecoration: 'underline',
                                color: palette.primary.main,
                                '&:hover': {
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    color: palette.primary.light,
                                },
                            }}
                        >
                            Already have an account? Login here
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    )
}

export default FormRegister
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `values` as parameter in onSubmit to pass to your `handleFormSubmit` method and also change `form` with `Form` because you using `Formik` so why not use all of it.
In initialValues `userType` is not getting updated and that's why your onSubmit is not getting called ,so you have to replace your existing  code to this so it can update `userType` value because it's required in the validationSchema

```
   <TextField
      id="outlined-select"
      select
      label="Select Type"
      name="userType"
      value={values.userType}
      onChange={handleChange}
      defaultValue="student"
    >
```

Full code:

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  MenuItem,
  TextField,
  Typography,
  useMediaQuery,
  useTheme
} from "@mui/material";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import * as yup from "yup";

const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required("required"),
  lastName: yup.string().required("required"),
  userType: yup.string().required("required"),
  userName: yup.string().required("required"),
  email: yup.string().email("invalid email").required("required"),
  password: yup.string().required("required"),
  confirmPassword: yup.string().required("required")
});

const initialValuesRegister = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  userType: "",
  userName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  confirmPassword: ""
};

const type = [
  {
    value: "Student",
    label: "Student"
  },
  {
    value: "Teacher",
    label: "Teacher"
  }
];

const FormRegister = () => {
  const { palette } = useTheme();
  // const navigate = useNavigate();
  const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");

  const register = async (values) => {
    const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3001/auth/register",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
      }
    );

    const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json();
  

    if (savedUser) {
      console.log(savedUser);
      navigate("/");
    }
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log("Test");
    console.log(values);
    // await register(values);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValuesRegister}
      onSubmit={(values, {resetForm}) => {
           handleFormSubmit(values);
           resetForm()
      }}
      validationSchema={registerSchema}
    >
      {({
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleBlur,
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        resetForm
      }) => (
        <Form>
          <Box
            display="grid"
            gap="30px"
            gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
            sx={{
              "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" }
            }}
          >
            <TextField
              label="First Name"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.firstName}
              name="firstName"
              error={Boolean(touched.firstName) && Boolean(errors.firstName)}
              helperText={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Last Name"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.lastName}
              name="lastName"
              error={Boolean(touched.lastName) && Boolean(errors.lastName)}
              helperText={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
            />
            <TextField
              id="outlined-select"
              select
              label="Select Type"
              name="userType"
              value={values.userType}
              onChange={handleChange}
              defaultValue="student"
            >
              {type.map((option) => (
                <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                  {option.label}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </TextField>
            <TextField
              label="User Name"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.userName}
              name="userName"
              error={Boolean(touched.userName) && Boolean(errors.userName)}
              helperText={touched.userName && errors.userName}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Email"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.email}
              name="email"
              error={Boolean(touched.email) && Boolean(errors.email)}
              helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.password}
              name="password"
              error={Boolean(touched.password) && Boolean(errors.password)}
              helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Confirm Password"
              type="password"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.confirmPassword}
              name="confirmPassword"
              error={
                Boolean(touched.confirmPassword) &&
                Boolean(errors.confirmPassword)
              }
              helperText={touched.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
            />
          </Box>
          {/* BUTTONS */}
          <Box>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              sx={{
                m: "2rem 0",
                p: "1rem",
                backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
                color: palette.background.alt,
                "&:hover": { color: palette.primary.main }
              }}
            >
              {" "}
              REGISTER
            </Button>
            <Typography
              onClick={() => {
                navigate("/");
                resetForm();
              }}
              sx={{
                textDecoration: "underline",
                color: palette.primary.main,
                "&:hover": {
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  color: palette.primary.light
                }
              }}
            >
              Already have an account? Login here
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default FormRegister;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it's working perfectly. What was the problem?

Comment: i updated my answer with explanation

Comment: Thanks. Weird thing with values because in my login form was working.

Comment: worked the first time. Tried to change something. Copy-pasted the code again and now it's not working..

Comment: Can you tell me any error if it's showing? Or can provide codesandbox link , because i just re-ran the code and it's working for me

Comment: No errors. When i press Register nothing happens. Trying to upload the files in my codesandbox

Comment: You changed anything in your answer?First time was working.

Comment: ya i just removed the extra code

Comment: Codesandbox takes ages to upload the whole project and i have to go. Thanks i will test it again later. Weird maybe something broke down. No errors. Nothing happens when i press the Register button i guess the problem is there. onSubmit.

Comment: i found it why  it's not working , becase of validatinSchema if you comment it it's working idk why its happening thou

Comment: i fixed it you can check my updated answer and if have any doubt just lemme know

Comment: Thanks. Probably yup problems i made mistakes or something i will check it again

Comment: probably bcz its not showing any error under select field and also you were not updating the userType value